# IIS Authorization Rules With .net Core 2.0

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on a .net core 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2017. When publishing this project to the IIS Server the Authorization Rules get reset every time the site is published from Visual Studio. I'm using Web Deploy to publish the site. I'd like to restrict users to the Domain Admins group and not have it default to allow all users.

It seems IIS stores this in the web.config file but it get overwritten every time Visual Studio publishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add web.config file to your project - at the same level as appsettings.json resides.

Publish should pick it up.

Comment: I copied the modified web.config into my project as suggested. After running a publish it keeps the settings. Thanks.